# How can I enable production mode in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, error-handling, production-environment

I have a copy of my Symfony 4 application on my server. When it is in developement mode it works fine.
In my .env file I have dev mode active:

```
APP_ENV=dev
```

But now I want my project on the server turn to production mode. So I changed the line to

```
APP_ENV=prod
```

But now I see only a blank page. The error log is not updated. What can I do? If I change the line back again to dev, everything works fine...

(I am on a shared host so I am not sure if this is Apache or Nginx)

Comment: I am very curious about the downvote reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you still have to clear (and if you want) warmup the cache of your new environment. You can do this from the command line:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

then

```
php bin/console cache:warmup
```

Comment: I tested `php bin/console cache:clear` in the terminal but the output is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /is/htdocs/myhost/www/project/bin/console on line 2`

Comment: I don't know why you see this error. Maybe it has to do with your version of PHP, but I am not sure. Or maybe with your terminal? One last thing I can suggest is just try `bin/console cache:clear` (so without the `php`)

Comment: -This gives the output: `bash: bin/console: Permission denied`

Comment: probably php version conflict.  php -v gives me `php 5.6` but Symfony 4 needs 7.1. But actually on the host I setup the php version to 7.1... only terminal says something else..confusion

Comment: But this also does not make sense. Because in the dev mode it works all fine on the server